# Python matches the part after a .* at its last occurance

Tags: python, regex, python-3.x

Im trying to read the server states from the guildwars API. For that i match the servername, then comes an occasional language specifier and a ",\n which i intend to match with .* and after that follows the population. But instead of directly matching the first occurrence of population it instead matches the last one. Can someone tell me why( and how to fix this)?

Edit: I found a workaround. By substituting .* with .{,20} it works.

```
relevant part of the API
"name": "Riverside [DE]",
"population": "Full"


with urlopen('https://api.guildwars2.com/v2/worlds?ids=all') as api:
s = api.read()
s = s.decode('utf-8')
search = re.search(r'''Riverside.*"population": "''',s,re.S)
print(search)
s = s[search.span()[1]:]
state = re.search(r'[a-zA-Z]*',s)
print(state)
```

Comment: If you need to extract a value from JSON, use JSON parser.

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew its more about why it takes the last and not the first match, i already have a workaround

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are two things

1. You should use .*?(trailing question mark) which will stop at the first instance.I wont think this as good or better solution
2. Instead once you get the data convert it into JSON and do your manipulation on top of it

> ```
> import json
>
> with urlopen('https://api.guildwars2.com/v2/worlds?ids=all') as api:
>   s = api.read()
>   s = s.decode('utf-8')
>   jsondata = json.loads(s)
>   filtered_data = filter(lambda a: str(a["name"]).find("Riverside") > -1,jsondata)
>   print(filtered_data[0]["population"])
> ```

Comment: why does the ? lead to stopping at the first instance?

Comment: Because thats a lazy regex expression which means match shortest possible string.

Comment: oh and here i thought that would be the default cause noone would ever want the longest one...

Comment: @Eumel [Greediness](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2301285/what-do-lazy-and-greedy-mean-in-the-context-of-regular-expressions) is often about performance. If you're trying to match `a*b`, you'll match `aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaab` faster if `*` is greedy. In cases where you don't care *what* matches as long as it *does* match, you end up wanting greedy quantifiers a lot.